# How to localize Google Ads for App Install Campaign?

Tags: localization, ads, google-ads-api

I am trying to create App Campaign available for many countries and languages. The App Name and all contents are in seven different languages.

My question is:
Is it possible to set up a single App campaign, so that all add assets (including text and App Store images) are localized by Google automatically?

I mean, I will write "Remember the Colors" in ad assets, and it shows "Remember the Colors" in UK (if the phone language is English) with English version of the App name
AND "Recuerda los Colores" in Spain (if the phone language is Spanish) with Spanish version of the App name.

Thank you in advance for your support.

I may create different app campaigns, but prefer to have single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to setup a different campaign for each region unfortunately.  Locations can only be assigned at campaign level in Google Ads.

https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/1722043?hl=en